# Range not respected in a function?

Tags: c, struct

This is a very simple program I made to test some stuff with structs which I'm new with.

If you try to execute the program, you'll notice that the first `if` in the void function is ignored (or maybe not satisfied) even when `19 <= BMI <= 25`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef struct {
        char name[50];
        float weigth;
        float heigth;
        float BMI;
} subjects;
void check_BMI(subjects Candidate)
{
        if (Candidate.BMI >= 19 && Candidate.BMI <= 25)
                puts("Subject is probably in good shape");
        else
                puts("Subject might not be in good shape");
}
int main()
{
        subjects Candidate;
        Candidate.BMI = Candidate.weigth/(Candidate.heigth * Candidate.heigth);
        puts("Insert subject's name: ");
        fgets(Candidate.name, 50, stdin);
        puts("Insert subject's weigth (in kg): ");
        scanf("%f", &Candidate.weigth);
        puts("Insert subject's heigth (in m): ");
        scanf("%f", &Candidate.heigth);
        check_BMI(Candidate);
        return 0;
}
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: `Candidate.BMI = Candidate.weigth/(Candidate.heigth * Candidate.heigth);`  move to after input (before `check_BMI(Candidate);`).

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: Do you actually calculate the BMI *BEFORE* you fetch the values from the input? :D

Comment: @Nitram: some programming languages work that way: [What is the difference between declarative and imperative programming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1784664/2564301). But C does not.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it in the wrong order:

```
    Candidate.BMI = Candidate.weigth/(Candidate.heigth * Candidate.heigth);
    puts("Insert subject's name: ");
    fgets(Candidate.name, 50, stdin);
    puts("Insert subject's weigth (in kg): ");
    scanf("%f", &Candidate.weigth);
    puts("Insert subject's heigth (in m): ");
```

You can't calculate the BMI as ratio of two numbers that haven't yet been entered. How is that supposed to work?

Move the BMI calculating line to a place after you've entered all numbers, and before you print the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
subjects Candidate;
```

which is uninitialized. Right after the declaration, you use

```
Candidate.BMI = Candidate.weigth/(Candidate.heigth * Candidate.heigth);
```

which calculates `Canditate.BMI` with the uninitialized values (garbage:`Candidate.weigth` , `Candidate.heigth`). This leads to Undefined Behavior.

Fix the problem by moving

```
Candidate.BMI = Candidate.weigth/(Candidate.heigth * Candidate.heigth);
```

just before

```
check_BMI(Candidate);
```

so that the values are initialized when calculating `Canditate.BMI`.

Comment: Thanks, how stupid am I? I've got an exam in about 30 minutes and I can't do stuff properly. It was a stupid mistake, got it, thanks.

Comment: @GiorgioDT , Never mind. It happens to all of us occasionally... And you're welcome! :-)