# How to get currentTarget object by click

Tags: vue.js

When I use Jquery to get a object from current target it's work fine.

But same behavior I would like to achieve by vueJs but VueJs returns a dom not a object.

Using Jquery

```
    <a onclick="test(this)" type="button">Button</a>

    function test(e){
      console.log($(e));
    })
```

Result :

```
init [a.cursor_pointer, context: a.cursor_pointer]
    0: a.cursor_pointer
    context: a.cursor_pointer
    length: 1
    __proto__: Object(0)
```

Using VueJs

```
<a @click="test" type="button">Read more</a>

 methods:{
    test(e){
       console.log(e.target);
    }
}
```

Result :

```
<a type="button" class="cursor_pointer">Read more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR; For what you are trying to do, there is no 1:1 jQuery to Vue equivalent.**

It looks like you're logging <s>jQuery's event</s> `this` (the `<a>` element, in this context), coerced into a jQuery [prototype] object, in your jQuery example.

The `e.target` in your Vue example is equivalent to the unadorned `e` in your jQuery click handler.

By wrapping `e` in `$()` in `test()`, you are imbuing the `<a>` with the jQuery prototype (so it has access to the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/) and all of its methods).

There is no direct equivalent to the jQuery prototype in Vue but you can:

1. Include jQuery IN your Vue app
2. or, use equivalent vanilla JavaScript on the `e.target` to accomplish something similar. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ is a pretty good resource if you are not comfortable digging through the [jQuery Source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

**EDIT** In light of your clarification (which you should edit into your original question), it looks like you have encountered the key difference between how one approaches a problem with jQuery versus the approach in frameworks such as Vue, React, Angular (et cetera). That is to say, the difference between imperative and declarative programming. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33656983/5796134) is a good description of that difference.

To do what you want in the "Vue way" you might create a [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) for your "review" blocks, with each review handling its "Read More/Read Less" state and toggling accordingly.

You *could* accomplish what you want in a Vue application using vanilla JavaScript *or* by including jQuery and adding your click listener in the `mounted` [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). While not *wrong*, it isn't taking advantage of Vue's declarative-ness.

Comment: When i use `console.log( e.target )` in Jquery nothing to show in console. I would like to achieve same result like Jquery  `(console.log($(e))` in vueJs

Comment: Vue won't give you the jQuery prototype that you are getting by wrapping the `e` in `$()` without also including jQuery in your build. Are you doing something with the `$(e)` that relies on jQuery [prototype] methods?