# How to pass data out of map function to sibling component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shopping cart which uses `map` to render several cards based on array objects. Each card contains item price, item quantity which can be increased by clicking the button, and item total price = price * quantity. There is an info bar at the bottom, which I'd like to show total price of all cards as user clicks the add button. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hamilton-4o1l1?

Here is the code:

Home.js:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import Infobar from './Infobar';

const Home = () => {
    const dummyData = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'hat',
            price: 10
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'tshirt',
            price: 11
        }
    ]

    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState([]);

    const changeItemQuantity = (id, itemQty) => {
        let _newState = [...quantity];
        let _itemInfo = _newState.find(item => item.id === id);
        if (_itemInfo !== undefined) {
            _itemInfo.itemQty += 1;
        } else {
            _newState.push({ id: id, itemQty: itemQty + 1 });
        };

        setQuantity(_newState);
    }

    const RenderCards = () => {
        let _totalPrice = 0;
        return (
            dummyData.map(
                (d) => {
                    const stateItem = quantity.find(item => item.id === d.id);
                    const itemQty = stateItem ? stateItem.itemQty : 0;
                    _totalPrice += d.price * itemQty;
                    console.log(_totalPrice); // correct value to send to Infobar
                    return (
                        <Card
                            key={d.id}
                            id={d.id}
                            title={d.title}
                            price={d.price}
                            quantity={itemQty}
                            changeItemQuantity={changeItemQuantity}
                            itemTotalPrice={d.price * itemQty}
                        />
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            <RenderCards/>
            <Infobar totalPrice={0}/> // here Infobar should take total price as an input
        </>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Card.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({ id, title, price, quantity, changeItemQuantity, itemTotalPrice }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div key={id}>
                <p>{id}. {title}</p>
                <p>Quantity: {quantity}</p>
                <p>Price: {price}</p>
                <p>Item total price: {itemTotalPrice}</p>
                <button onClick={() => changeItemQuantity(id, 0)}>Add item</button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Card
```

Infobar.js:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Infobar = ({ totalPrice }) => {
    return (

        <div>Total Price: {totalPrice}</div>

    )
}

export default Infobar;
```

Now the problem is, total price of all items in Infobar does not change (I passed 0 as dummy data). I need to calculate the total price of all items and pass it to `Infobar`. I have calculated the correct value in `_totalPrice` in RenderCards, how can I pass `_totalPrice` to Infobar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [updated the Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-lederberg-fvz2z?file=/src/Home.js) you need to use internal state to cause a rerender.

You should really take a look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). At least read 1 - 12 of the Main Concepts section and the section on hooks. There are several parts of the example you provided where you are opting for mutation and imperative statements which will not work with React.

**Updated Sanbox**

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-babbage-g6m4b?file=/src/Home.js)

**Imperative vs Declarative React**

[Here are great examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655534/difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-in-react-js) that explain the difference.

Rather than giving specific instructions such as trying to mutate the `totalPrice` variable opt for `useState` and `useEffect` and let your jsx be a result of state and props.

Comment: I tried your solution before asking, setting a state inside the map was intuitive, but the reason I didn't do it was this console error: index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Home`) while rendering a different component (`RenderCards`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `RenderCards`, follow the stack trace as described in ...

Comment: Check the sandbox, although the code works, it creates a console error each time clicking the button.

Comment: That is due to the way you've rendered the cards. I will post an updated sandbox shortly

Comment: Also can you please elaborate a bit about 'I'm opting for mutation and imperative statements which will not work with React'?

Answer (score 0):

why not just add a new state `const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);`  the same way you set quantity?  you set the total where you put your log and pass the total to your Infobar component.

However although it works I see some issues in the way you have put the code, for once why would you create a component inside your home component and not just let Card handle all the logic?

Comment: I tried your first solution before asking and got this console error: cannot update a component while rendering a different component.

Comment: The reason I put the logic in `Home` is some shared data needs to be passed to other components apart from `Card`, so I tried to put all logic in `Home` and pass the data down to its children.