# How to return a request function from useQuery in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a React hook that returns a request functions that call an API

It has the following code:

```
export const useGetFakeData = () => {
  const returnFakeData = () =>
    fetch('https://fake-domain.com').then(data => console.log('Data arrived: ', data))

  return returnFakeData
}
```

And then I use this hook in component something like this

```
const getFakeData = useGetFakeData()

useEffect(() => getFakeData(), [getFakeData])
```

How to achieve this effect in react-query when we need to return a request function from custom hook?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging in docs, I find out that React-Query in useQuery hook provide a **refetch()** function.

In my case, I just set property **enabled** to false (just so that the function when mount is not called automatically), and just return a request-function like this

```
export const useGetFakeData = () => {
  const { refetch } = useQuery<void, Error, any>({
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch('https://fake-domain.com').then(data => console.log('Data arrived: ', data)),
    queryKey: 'fake-data',
    enabled: false,
  })

  return refetch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`useMutation`](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useMutation#_top) hook if you want to request the data using the imperative way. The `data` returned from the hook is the latest resolved value of the mutation call:

```
const [mutate, { data, error }] = useMutation(handlefunction);

useEffect(() => {
  mutate(...);
}, []);
```

Comment: Do you think this is truly mutation? I was thinking that mutation is a process on changing something, registration process via POST methods for example, not the GET request

Comment: @BorisLebedev `useMutation` is suitable for post/put/delete actions because it's natural to execute them in the imperative way (when you click the delete button, you **order** the mutate function to do sth). `useQuery` is suitable for fetching data because it's the the declarative way to use in react - when the component mounts, you declare the props and the shape of data and how the data should display inside the component. It doesn't mean that you're forbidden to use `useMutation` to fetch data, it's just not a conventional way to do so,...

Comment: @BorisLebedev  and since your question ask for a way to request the data the imperative way, you can use this `useMutation` approach. See the differences between imperative/declarative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655534/difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for the standard react-query behaviour, which is to fire off a request when the component mounts (unless you disable the query). In your example, that would just be:

```
export const useGetFakeData = () =>
  useQuery('fakeData', () => fetch('https://fake-domain.com'))
}


const { data } = useGetFakeData()
```

Please be advised that this is just a bare minimal example:

- if you have dependencies to your fetch, they should [go into the query key](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)
- for proper error handling with fetch, you'll have to [transform the result to a failed Promise](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#usage-with-fetch-and-other-clients-that-do-not-throw-by-default)