# What are RxJS Subject's and the benefits of using them?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, subject

I found the [rxJS docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject) define them as

> What is a Subject? An RxJS Subject is a special type of Observable that allows values to be multicasted to many Observers. While plain Observables are unicast (each subscribed Observer owns an independent execution of the Observable), Subjects are multicast.

and it goes on to give examples but I'm looking for a basic ELI5 explanation. From my understanding is it helps handle and define items in a sequence. Is that correct?

I think it would be most helpful to me and others to see a simple function with and without defining an **rxJS Subject** to understand why it's important?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any experience with rxjs Observable yet?

Comment: A little. From what I understand they help make things async, and they're also very similar to promises.

Comment: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/subjects.html

Answer (score 37):

The easiest way to understand it is to think of a `Subject` as both a *producer* and a *consumer*. It's like an open channel where someone can send a message on one end, and any subscribers will receive it on the other end.

```
                                  +---------------
Sender                            | =>  =>  =>  =>  Subscriber
           -----------------------+   +----------- 
Message =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  =>  Subscriber
           -----------------------+   +-----------
                                  | =>  =>  =>  =>  Subscriber
                                  +---------------
```

In code terms say you have a service with a subject

```
class MessageService {
  private _messages = new Subject<Message>();

  get messages: Observable<Message> {
    return this._messages.asObservable();
  }

  sendMessage(message: Message) {
    this._messages.next(message);
  }
}
```

Note the `messages` getter returning the Subject as an Observable. This is not *required*. The `Subject` is already an observable, and anybody could subscribe directly to the `Subject`. But I think the `asObservable` pattern is used as a way to limit what users can do with it, i.e. so users only use it to *subscribe* to, and not *emit* to. We save the emitting for the `sendMessage` method.

Now with this service in place, we can inject it into different components, and this can be a way for two (or more) arbitrary components to communicate (or just receive arbitrary event notifications).

```
class ComponentOne {
  constructor(private messages: MessageService) {}

  onClick() {
    this.messages.sendMessage(new Message(..));
  }
}

class ComponentTwo {
  constructor(private messages: MessageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages.messages.subscribe((message: Message) => {
      this.message = message;
    });
  }
}
```

Angular's own [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.1/modules/%40angular/facade/src/async.ts#L61) is actually a `Subject`. When we subscribe to the `EventEmitter`, we are subscribing to a `Subject`, and when we `emit` on the `EventEmitter`, we are sending a message through the `Subject` for all subscribers.

#### See also:

- [Subject vs BehaviorSubject vs ReplaySubject in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43118769/2587435)

Answer (score 11):

Subjects are useful when the code you're in is the one that is actually originating the observable data. You can easily let your consumers subscribe to the `Subject` and then call the `next()` function to push data into the pipeline.

If, however, you are getting data from other source and are just passing it along (perhaps transforming it first), then you most likely want to use one of the creation operators shown [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#creation-operators), such as `Rx.Observable.fromEvent` [like so](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent):

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
clicks.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

This allow you to stay in the functional paradigm, whereas using a `Subject`, while it has its uses, is considered by some to be a smell that you're trying to force imperative code into a declarative framework.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1784702/1672027) is a great answer that explains the difference in the two paradigms.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the most simple explanation ...

Observables are usually the result of something. The result of an http call, and whatever you do with a pipe returns an observable.

But what is the source of those things? Ever wondered how you hook your user events into the whole rxjs thing? The main feature of subjects is that you can call the next() method on them.

When doing reactive programming, the first step is usually to make a list of possible subject you will have.

For instance: lets say we have to make a todo-list app.
We will probably have a couple of variables in our component:

```
public deleteItem$ = Subject<TodoItem> = new Subject();
public addItem$ = Subject<TodoItem> = new Subject();
public saveList$ = Subject<TodoItem[]> = new Subject();
```

and in our applicatiuon we will hook these up like this:

```
<button (click)="deleteItem$.next(item)">Delete</button>
```

Using rxjs, we will use operators like merge/combineLatest/withLatestFrom to handle these subjects and define our application logic.

I'll see if I can find the time to make a small example.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a study of the semantics of subjects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849873/what-are-the-semantics-of-different-rxjs-subjects/34860777#34860777).

All answered I see are correct. I'll just add that the term `subject` comes from the observer pattern (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). As such a subject is sort of a relay, it receives something on one end, and emit it on any of its ends (subscriptions).