# How to display the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

`Array1` and `Array2` have connections to each other:

```
var Array1 = ['Bob','James','Kanye','West'];
var Array2 = [0,1,2,3];
var Array3 = [1,3,0,2];
```

How do I display it to this?

```
Array4 = ['James', 'West', 'Bob','Kanye'];
```

Comment: Please see: [ask]

Comment: What have you tried up to this point? Can you provide some code you've attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will require 2 loops, 1 will go through each element of Array3 and Second loop will be used to find the index value will be compared with Array2 to find index of Array 1 and then that index value will be saved in Array4 from Array1

```
 for (var i = 0; i < Array3.length; i++) 
 {
    var index = Array3[i];
    var position=-1;
    for(var j=0; j < Array2.length;j++)
    {
       if(index==Array2[j])
       {
          position = j;
          break;         
       }
    }
    Array4[i] = Array1[j];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a loop over Array, take the integer inside as indexnumber,  then you print out the first array with the numbers you just took from the first array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -- and read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for -- arrays' `map` method:

```
const names  = ['Bob','James','Kanye','West'];
const order = [1,3,0,2];
const orderedNames = order.map(x => names[x]);
console.log(orderedNames);
// => ["James", "West", "Bob", "Kanye"]
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/68hrrjx3/

Also kinda relevant in the context of the other answers: [What is the difference between declarative and imperative programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784664/what-is-the-difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-programming)