# Loop inside function in PHP

Tags: php, html, function, loops

[How do I write a php program that will show this output using 2 functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04xrK.png)

I know this code is wrong but it should look something close to this, functions confuse me

```
<body>

<table border="1">
<tr><th>i</th><th>square</th><th>cube</th></tr>


<?php 

function square($x)

{
return $x * $x ;

}
function cube($y)
{
        return $y * $y * $y ;
}
for ($i=1; $i <= 10 ; $i++) 
    echo "

<tr>
    <td>$i</td>
    <td>square('$i');</td>
    <td>cube('$i');</td>

</tr>";


 ?>

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey@Ahmad Soliman, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask questions .

Comment: break out of php or use concatination

Answer (score 0):

The function calls are not concatenated right:

```
<style>
     table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
     }

     table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
     }
</style>
<body>

<table style="border: 1">
     <tr>
          <th>i</th>
          <th>square</th>
          <th>cube</th>
     </tr>

     <?php 

     function square($x){
          return $x * $x ;
     }
     function cube($y){
          return $y * $y * $y ;
     }
     for ($i=1; $i <= 10 ; $i++) 
          echo "
          <tr>
               <td>$i</td>
               <td>".square($i)."</td>
               <td>".cube($i)."</td>

          </tr>";
     ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to what you want. You should change your "for" loop so that your code will finally look something like the following lines:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>i</th><th>square</th><th>cube</th></tr>
    <?php
    function square($x) {
        return $x * $x ;
    }
    function cube($y) {
        return $y * $y * $y ;
    }
    for ($i=1; $i <= 10 ; $i++){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo square($i); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo cube($i); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow. Majed's answer is correct, and should probably be marked as the accepted answer. I'd recommend a few other changes though.

1. [Separation of Concern](https://nalexn.github.io/separation-of-concerns/): **Fewer lines of code does not necessarily mean it's simpler or easier to maintain. Bite-sized chunks, and fewer decision branches therein, does.** In its most basic form this principle dictates that you not mix your algorithm logic with your presentation logic.

`view.php`

```
<style>
     table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
     }

     table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
     }
</style>
<body>

<table style="border: 1">
     <tr>
          <th>i</th>
          <th>square</th>
          <th>cube</th>
     </tr>

     <?php 
     foreach ($powers as $index => $power) {
          echo "<tr><td>$index</td>";
          foreach ($power as $value) {
               echo "<td>$value</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
     }
     ?>
</table>
</body>
```

`exponentHelpers.php`

```
    function square($x)
    {
        return $x * $x ;
    }
    function cube($y)
    {
        return $y * $y * $y ;
    }
```

`controller.php`

```
require_once "exponentHelpers.php";

$base = 10;
$powers = [];

while($base--) {    //Note, the self-decrementing short-hand will result in the values listed in reverse order.
                    //You could write it long-hand if you prefer, or call array_reverse() afterwards.
    $powers[] = [
        square($base),
        cube($base),
    ];
}


require_once "view.php";
```

2. [PSR2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/): Never too soon to learn good habits. PSR2 basically describes an industry-standard of formatting your code to keep it looking consistent and easy to read regardless who wrote it. You have a couple violations there.

- Tabs should be 4 spaces, not 5.
- Opening brackets for functions should be on a new line.
- Avoid single-line control structures. i.e, use brackets for loops and if-statements:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= 10 ; $i++) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$i</td>
            <td>".square($i)."</td>
            <td>".cube($i)."</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

3. [Power function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php): You kind of reinvented the wheel with your `square()` and `cube()` functions. Php provides a `pow($base, $exponent)` function that does the same thing, and isn't limited to one power. So this could do away the `exponentHelpers.php` section altogether.
4. PSR2-compliant shorthand: Entirely your preference if you want to use this, but there are two bits of Php you might be intersted in here, looking at the loops in the `view.php` section. One is [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which allows for [imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784664/what-is-the-difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-programming#:%7E:text=Declarative%20programming%20%3A%20is%20a%20programming,control%20flow(How%20do).&text=It%20emphasizes%20the%20application%20of,which%20emphasizes%20changes%20in%20state.) array looping and result retrieval on the same line. The other is [`<?=`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), which is HTML-template shorthand for `<?php echo ...`. Put them together, and you could present your loops more succinctly:

```
<?= array_map(function (array $power, $index) {
    //Newlines are optional. Just makes the output a little easier to read.
    $powerElms = preg_replace("/^.*$/", "<td>$0</td>", $power);
    return "<tr>\n<td>$index</td>\n" . implode("\n", $powerElms) . "</tr>\n";
}, $powers, array_keys($powers)) //Missing semicolon is not a typo. It's not needed with this syntax. ?>
```

Comment: Even the `pow()` function is unnecessary, since `$i ** 2` exists.